# Is there a css selector based on whether an element has a particular property?

Tags: css, magento, css-selectors

I am working with Magento which doesn't allow for classes on images in the visual editor; so I want to program it to automatically apply right margin to an image **if** the image has the property `float:left` ... and visa versa. Is this possible without using javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's part of the `style` attribute, then sure: `[style*='float:left']`

Comment: Yes this one works all right - http://jsfiddle.net/bbFft/ - I haven't been able to get it working in Magento yet but that's another issue which I'll sort later, so cheers.

Comment: **NB** Point to watch out for is that `[style*='float:left']` and `[style*='float: left']` are different (note whitespace) ... obvious but easy to spend an hour tearing hair out over too. ( That was my Magento Problem as magento was generating `float: left` not `float:left` )

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a selector based on CSS properties, apart from scanning selecting on the [style attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11767550/1139697) - after all you set them with CSS.

The easiest way would be to set the `margin-right` property at the same place where you set the `float` property.

See also:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors
- http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#overview

Comment: no float properly is being set by a button by the client in the editor.

Comment: If the `float` gets set by a button, then `margin-right` should be set by the very same button too.

Comment: I know but it isn't ... to be honest I don't think magento's editor is very good in this area  - all it does is float the image right or left; margins can be applied around the whole image aright but that's no help ... or do you know something I don't because it would be great if that was possible ? The way Wordpress does it, for example, is ideal where instead of applying a style it applies a class like .alignright giving the dev the opportunity to style the class.

Comment: Sorry, I completely ignored the [tag:magento], skimmed your question and basically read "Is there a css selector based on whether an element has a particular property? Is this possible without using javascript?" If you tend to apply a `float` on all your images try to include this into your stylesheet instead. However, I believe it won't show up in magento :/.

Comment: Yes I know what you're saying but Magento applies this float as generated content when the user selects "align right" or "align left" on the image in the editor ( in the magento admin section) ... So I  cant override it because it's programmed into the core I'm sure. It's silly the way they do it they should apply a class like Wordpress does, but they literally apply the float property right in the editor so there's nothing to latch on to.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all of your styles are placed in an external stylesheet the answer's 'not without javascript'.

If, however, you're placing that specific style on the html (inline styles, that is) then what Kolink suggested does work.

Anyway, using javascript(jQuery) here's a possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/TECWM/
If you can't see the fiddle, it goes something like this:

```
    if (el.css('float') === 'left') {
        el.css({
            'margin-left': '50px'
        });
    }
```